# Displaying Contents of an ArrayList that contains objects of another class with private fields

Tags: java, arraylist

How do I print the album title from the array-list if the contents of the object is in a private field in another class?

Display Method

```
public void displayAllAlbums() {

   for (int i = 0; i < AlbumList.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println(AlbumList.get(i));
    }
}
```

Album Class that has private variables title and price.

```
class Album {

    private String title;
    private double price;

    Album(String title, double price) {

        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }
}
```

Cart Class adds songs to arraylist can also get total

```
import java.util.*;

public class Cart {

List<Album> AlbumList = new ArrayList<Album>();
```

Main Method putting albums into addAlbum method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cart cart1 = new Cart();

    Album album1 = new Album("ye", 20);
    Album album2 = new Album("MBDTF", 16);

    cart1.addAlbum(album1);
    cart1.addAlbum(album2);

    System.out.println(cart1.getTotalAlbums());
    cart1.displayAllAlbums();

}
```

adding album to the arralist

```
public void addAlbum(Album album) {
    AlbumList.add(album);
}
```

Unsure on how to display the album

```
public void displayAllAlbums() {
    for (int i = 0; i < AlbumList.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println(AlbumList.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this.

```
public void displayAllAlbums() {
    for (int i = 0; i < AlbumList.size(); i++) {
        Album album = AlbumList.get(i)
        System.out.println(album.getTitle() + " "+ album.getPrice());
    }
}
```

Your Arraylist's objects are actually Album object. So when are accessing an ArrayList object via AlbumList.get(i) command, you're getting an Album object instance. So you pass it on to Album variable. Then access the private field via getter methods you've set up earlier!

Cheers!

Comment: Cheers! The explanation helped me understand the answer.

Comment: @ConnorJones, Thanks mate. If you are helped by my answer, please upvote it and may be accept it as an answer! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either by overriding toString() method in Album class or by providing a public method for displaying the properties.

```
 class Album {

    private String title;
    private double price;

    Album(String title, double price) {

        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;

    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

@Override
    public String toString(){
      return "title:"+title+",price:"+price;
    }
    }
```

While you passing the object to **System.out.println(AlbumList.get(i))**, the toString() method will get invoke and print album title and price.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I print the album title from the array-list

Just use the public accesor method i.e. `Album#getTitle()`

```
public void displayAllAlbums() {
   for (Album album : AlbumList) {
        System.out.printf("Album title: %s%n",album.getTitle());
    }
}
```